# I've added an li to my ul, while it works, it's causing an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used a template which has some nice scrolling effects (https://www.freshdesignweb.com/demo/template/ubusina/#carouselHacked), however, I've added an external link to the end of the `ul` and it seems to work – but it's causing errors!

when I scroll I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://mylink.com/blog/

I believe the first section of JavaScipt code below is where it's breaking, but I'm unsure of how to fix it:

```
 function onScroll(event){
          var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
          $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a').each(function () {
              var currLink = $(this);
              var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
              if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
                  $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a').removeClass("active");
                  currLink.addClass("active");
              }
              else{
                  currLink.removeClass("active");
              }
          });
      }



      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a class="menu active" href="#home" title="Home" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu" href="#about">about </a></li>
            <li><a class="menu" href="#team" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu" href="#contact" title="Contact">contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank" >google</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Your link goes to a Chevrolet website that doesn't contain any of your code.  There's not enough here to reproduce the problem, so all the answers you''ll get are just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your code is trying to select an element using the `href` as a selector. `#home` is a valid jQuery ID selector, but `www.google.com` is not (incidentally your probably need `https://www.google.com`). Try filtering so only those that start with `#` get used.

```
function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        // Only apply to those tags that start with '#'.
        var href = currLink.attr("href");
        if (href.indexOf('#') === 0) {
            var refElement = $(href);
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
                $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a').removeClass("active");
                currLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I basically wrote the same thing, but this answer is better so I removed mine and upvoted.

Comment: Thanks guys. I updated the selector to: $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a[id]')

Answer (score 3):

I presume whatever template you are using expects your menu to have a certain structure, like the `class` attribute applied to the anchors within the menu. The anchor you added does not have this attribute.

Try changing this:

```
 <li><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank" >google</a></li>
```

To this:

```
 <li><a class="menu" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a></li>
```

Comment: Pretty sure that won't solve the JavaScript problem.

Comment: I don't tend to load up external websites in questions unless I recognize the domain. To your point, it may or may not solve a javascript problem, depending on what is doing the parsing - an external library vs the browser.

Comment: I haven't visited the link either, but `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression` is a jQuery exception meaning it was given an invalid selector.